# Using id_token for all user data instead of userinfo endpoint in OIDC

Tags: oauth2, openid-connect

I need to provide high security for user data. So I would have to encrypt `userinfo_endpoint` response (despite using TLS, these are the requirements I got).

But encrypting `userinfo_endpoint` response require a some mechanism to do key exchange between client and OIDC provider. It will add one more private key to manage it securely.

So I thought about a bit modified `id_token`. It will be signed and look like this:

```
{
   "iss": "...",
   "aud": "...",
   "iat": "...",
   "exp": "...",
   "nbf": "...",
   "at_hash": "...",
   "c_hash": "...",
   "s_hash": "...",
   "userinfo": "some-encrypted-token-using-nonce"
}
```

Where `userinfo` claim is e.g. JWE token encrypted using `nonce` used in `authorization_endpoint` and looks like it:

```
{
   "sub": "...",
   "email": "...",
   "some-very-sensitive-claim-about-health": "..."
}
```

This `userinfo` token will contain all data that we can receive using `userinfo_endpoint`. We still can verify nonce, because if we can't decrypt this token using available nonce, it means that nonce is invalid.

What do you think about it? My `id_token` is always received using `token_endpoint` and will never be stored (e.g. in cookie)

Are there any security considerations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that much simpler. Don't include health info into the user info response.

The purpose of user info endpoint is to provide information related to the authentication purposes. It does not need to include information about health, about bank accounts, about cars or realty owned by this user, about what purchases at what store has this user made, etc.

JWT/JWE should not be used a replacement of session data.

If you have an application related to health of the users, put health data to a separate service.

Even when you have such data in a separate service, check carefully if you really need additional encryption. Communication between client and server is encrypted by TLS. When data arrives to the client, client encrypts them. Also if you add your own encryption, the client will still decrypt it and see decrypted data. Don't you trust TLS? If you don't trust TLS, then how can you trust *any* other encryption?

The only case when additional encryption *might* have sense is the case when your your application is not TLS termination point, and when you don't trust the TLS termination point, or the traffic between TLS termination point and your application is rooted via untrusted network. But in case of sensitive data you should not put your application into a network with untrusted hosts. The network should include only your own hosts/pods. The TLS termination point should also be under your control. Thus network configuration should not be a reason for additional encryption.

Comment: Right, the authorization server will not return any health or other highly sensitive information. I don't know why I thought it's doing that. TLS will be sufficent for retrieving data like email etc. Thanks you.